# How to merge log data in python while data size is large

Tags: python, logging, merge

I need to merge data based on user_id but while merging it creates more than 10 million rows

I'm already tried

```
pd.merge(train,log,on=user_id) 

train.head()
   impression_time    user_id   app_code  os_version    is_4G   is_click
0  2018-11-15 00:00:00  87862   422     old              0  0
1  2018-11-15 00:01:00  63410   467     latest       1       1
2  2018-11-15 00:02:00  71748   259     intermediate      1      1
```

```
train.shape
((237609, 6)
```

```
log.head()

    server_time       device_type  session_id   user_id  item_id
0  2018-10-15 08:58:00  android     112333   4557    32970
1  2018-10-15 08:58:00  android     503590   74788   7640
2  2018-10-15 08:58:00  android     573960   23628   128855


(3118622, 5)
```

while merging data using

```
df=pd.merge(train,log,on='userid')
```

I'm getting around 10 million rows. how to tackle this situation?

10 million rows may effect the my ml mode?

Comment: how many records are there in final dataframe after merger??

Comment: Please don't use Indian words like 'crore' here. People will not understand that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use inner join when merging two dataframes.

```
result = pd.merge(train, log, how='inner', on='user_id')
```

Comment: result = pd.merge(train, log, how='inner', on='user_id')                                                           result :result.shape                                                                                                               
        (11052766, 11) same i crore rows I'm getting

Comment: So you are getting duplicate records as well?

Comment: how many columns you see in the result dataframe. are they equal to no of columns of both dataframe??

Comment: result getting 11 columns.No train have 7 columns & log have 5 columns ,based on user_id i'm merging the data